# cannot delete static route on mac

Tags: networking, macos, routing

On my MAC, a strange route appears every time I connect to a Wi-Fi network.

this is the routing table:

```
Internet:
Destination        Gateway            Flags        Refs      Use   Netif       Expire  
default            192.168.1.1        UGSc          111        0     en0  
127                127.0.0.1          UCS             0        0     lo0  
127.0.0.1          127.0.0.1          UH              1      170     lo0  
169.254            link#6             UCS             0        0     en0  
192.168.1          link#6             UCS             6        0     en0  
192.168.1.1/32     link#6             UCS             2        0     en0  
192.168.1.1        98:d:67:2c:21:e0   UHLWIir        61       13     en0     1059  
192.168.1.9        d8:9c:67:5e:3f:c9  UHLWI           0        7     en0   1175  
192.168.1.15/32    link#6             UCS             0        0     en0  
192.168.1.88       2c:f4:32:5b:48:41  UHLWI           0        0     en0     1196  
192.168.1.181      c:f9:c0:f1:de:ba   UHLWI           0       28     en0   1181  
192.168.1.190      48:d6:d5:60:f0:ab  UHLWIi          1       56     en0   1061  
192.168.1.217      78:3e:53:f4:d7:c2  UHLWI           0       28     en0   1181  
195.0.0/8          192.168.1.254      UGSc            0        0     en0  
224.0.0/4          link#6             UmCS            2        0     en0  
224.0.0.251        1:0:5e:0:0:fb      UHmLWI          0        0     en0  
239.255.255.250    1:0:5e:7f:ff:fa    UHmLWI          0        8     en0  
255.255.255.255/32 link#6             UCS             0        0     en0
```

strange route is the 195.0.0/8 with flag UGSc on non existing gateway 192.168.1.254

I'm able to delete using command:

```
sudo route -n delete 195.0.0.0/8
```

but when I disable and enable Wi-Fi that route is still there.

How can I delete it permanently?

Thanks

Comment: It seems to be related to a VPN service. Do you have a VPN client enabled on this machine, and if so, when you turn it off, does the same route still appear?

Comment: I have Pulse Secure but it is stopped

Comment: As long as it is installed on your machine, it's going to show up in your network adapters, physical or virtual, and it'll be polled same as the others when you launch a traceroute. If it's really bothersome, you can uninstall Pulse Secure. I'd advise a third-party instead of the built-in uninstaller, or there'll be leftovers in your Startup Items, be it user or System, and a few kexts here and there that macOS will start for nothing during boot. Up to you, but if you make a regular use of Pulse Secure, then you'll have to live with it showing up in your traceroutes.

Comment: I don't think is something related to Pulse Secure. I manually added that route months ago when I used a gateway on that ip 192.168.1.254. Now i don't have anymore that gw and sometimes i cannot reach sites in that network range